# Расширение ContentControl

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется некоторый `ContentControl` элемент. Мне нужно создать его расширенную версию, добавив новые возможности, а именно, опуская излишние подробности, представление множества дочерних элементов внутри. При этом, вызов `SetValue(ContentProperty)` должен добавлять новый элемент, а `GetValue(ContentProperty)` должен возвращать последний добавленный элемент. Как можно реализовать такое?

Comment: `UserControl` вам поможет. Можете его унаследовать от `ContentControl`, и дальше добавлять `DepencyProperty` в его код-бихайнде на свой вкус. Но есть вероятность, что ваша задача решается и без кастомных контролов, а посредством стилей и конвертеров, но это точно без излишних подробностей не узнать.

Comment: Вы не так поняли условие. Уже имеется некоторый элемент, унаследованный от `ContentControl`. И вот уже этот самый элемент необходимо расширить.

Comment: Ну тогда все тоже самое, только унаследуйтесь от некоторого элемента. :)

Comment: _"Можете его унаследовать от ContentControl, и дальше добавлять DepencyProperty в его код-бихайнде на свой вкус"_ - Но для реализации возможности добавления множества дочерних элементов не нужно добавлять какие то новый свойства зависимостей. Нужно в первую очередь переопределить метаданные `ContentProperty`. А потом подумать как в визуальное представление элемента в обработчике `OnContentChanged`  добавлять новые элементы. Контейнер подходящий выбрать.

Comment: Вот это интересно как сделать...

Comment: Вообще ведь пожалуй все `ContentControl` элементы имеют какое то своё визуальное представление помимо того, что мы задаём в свойстве `Content`. Ну элементарно `Button` содержит `ContentPresenter` и `Border`. При этом ведь никакого стиля по умолчанию, задающего такое представление, на сколько я знаю, не существует. Где это всё прописывается?

Comment: Абсолютно все контролы имеют хоть какой-то шаблон по умолчанию. Вы можете с тем же Blend'ом спокойно извлекать стили и шаблоны. Вообще зачем вам для таким странных целей ContentControl? У вас код жёстко привязан к данному типу? Почему не ItemsControl, раз у вас множество элементов?

Comment: _"У вас код жёстко привязан к данному типу?"_ - Да. Как можно изменить шаблон по умолчанию при наследовании? Не через свойство `Template` при создании элемента.

Comment: DefaultStyleKey в конструкторе переопредели на тип твоего наследника, а уже в Xaml описывал стиль, где в том числе можно и шаблон любой прописать. В ApplyTemplate ты можешь на ходу получать нужные тебе элементы, если имя дашь. Вообще для этого почитать парочку мануалов на том же Metanit нужно.

Comment: Свойство `Content` устанавливается раньше применения шаблона. Как положить элемент в нужный мне контейнер сразу? Сделать это в `OnApplyTemplate`? Или есть какие то более, так скажем, грамотные способы?